# Definição e implementação em locais diferentes

Tags: c++, header

Olá. Estou com dúvidas ao fazer a implementação de um cabeçalho em pastas com caminhos diferentes. Estou colocando meu cabeçalho em uma pasta chamada `"include"` e as implementações em uma pasta chamada `"src"`. Para resolver esse problema, estou fazendo o seguinte na implementação: `#include "../include/header.h"`

Minha dúvida é que, ao ver muitos códigos disponibilizados na internet, não se usa o "../" para ir ao diretório, onde muitos apenas incluem o nome do header. Por exemplo: `#include "header.h"`

Gostaria de saber como isso é possível, pois quando não caminho até o diretório correto, recebo erros de arquivo não encontrado. Inclusive, até mesmo os códigos prontos que baixo na internet eu preciso corrigir o diretório dos arquivos, pois recebo o mesmo erro.

Comment: Qual o método que usas para compilar o software? Make (makefile), outros?

Comment: Utilizo o terminal mesmo, ainda não aprendi a utilizar makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas servindo como pequeno exemplo, suponhamos que a estrutura do teu projecto é a seguinte:

```
Raiz
|-inc
| | foo.h
|-src
| | main.cpp
|-bin
  |
```

Conteudo dos ficheiros

**foo.h**

```
#include<string>

class Foo {

public:
    Foo(std::string nome) : nome_(nome) {}
    std::string getNome() { return nome_; }
private:
    std::string nome_;

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Foo foo("André");
    std::cout << "Hello " << foo.getNome() << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Para compilar este pequeno projecto directamente na linha de comandos podes executar o seguinte comando:

```
g++ -Iinc/ -o bin/foo src/main.cpp
```

A parte mais importante é indicar ao compilador, com a flag `-I` directorias adicionais onde procurar os ficheiros. Neste caso é a directoria `inc/`.

O resultado do comando irá colocar o executável na directoria `bin/`

Ainda que isto seja suficiente para um pequeno projecto, recomendaria que desses uma leitura no tópico sobre Makefile ou equivalente.